# verify a loop is calling elements with the same name from multiple lists

Tags: r, list, loops, names

I have two large lists (over 700 elements) that have the same element names.
The next step in my analyses is to calculate confidence intervals via a bootstrapping function written in C++. To use the function, I need to call elements from both lists, the raw data for a given individual and the model output for that individual.
My supervisor is concerned that the loop does not "match" element names between lists. Since one list was created from a function looped over  the other list, and neither list has had elements rearranged I am not overly concerned that there will be calls to non-matching elements, but it would be nice to make sure that the names match before running the function if we end up using this bootstrap function on data not generated via the same means as the current lists.

example lists:

```
lst_A <- list(
  m1 = matrix(1:12, nrow = 4), 
  m2 = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3), 
  m3 = matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)
)

lst_b <- list(m1 = c(t1 = 2, t2 = 2, r0 = 2, r1 = 2, k0 = 2, k1 = 2), 
m2 = c(t1 = 1, t2 = 1, r0 = 1, r1 = 1, k0 = 1, k1 = 1), 
m3 = c(t1 = 10, t2 = 10, r0 = 10, r1 = 10, k0 = 10, k1 = 10))
```

lst_A is a list of matrices of raw data, each matrix has the same number of columns but varying in number of rows. Matrices were required by the function that created lst_b, a list of lists.

I have a loop similar to the following that writes the results to another list:

```
out <- list()
ci_outs_names <- names(lst_A) 
for (i in seq_along(lst_A)) { 
  CIs = (lst_A[[i]] * lst_b[[i]])
  out[[ci_outs_names[i]]] <- CIs
}
```

I have not found an option to match elements of a list in a loop. Is this possible using loops, or is there another method that would allow element name matching when using multiple lists to inform a function? Please note that I am unable to modify the C++ code/functions.

If helpful, the "real" loop code is:

```
ci_out <- list()
ci_outs_names <- names(lst_A) 
for (i in seq_along(lst_A)) { 
    sourceCpp("cpp_functions.cpp") 
    CIs = bootstrap_CI(data_in = lst_A[[i]],
                       optim_pars = lst_b[[i]], 
                       n_iter = 100, 
                       times_matrix = times_matrix, intervals = c(14, 7, 3, 1), NLL_include = 5, cpp = TRUE) # These are all just additional arguments to another function which is called inside of this function
    ci_out[[ci_outs_names[i]]] <- CIs
   }
```

Note (probably not relevant to this question, but I will mention just in case): This code consistently crashes RStudio (white screen) even with `n_iter = 10` and lists of 2 elements. A scaled-down version (`n_iter = 50`) of this loop works on the full dataset in the console.

Comment: The multiplication is incorrect. The matrix is of size n * 3 yet the vector b is of length 6. How are you trying to multiply the two? Note that R is using recycling thats why you do not see an error

Comment: The multiplication and the lists are a simplistic example. The "real" code does not multiply the two. The functions in the real code pull specific columns from each list element and applies a function, as evidenced in the final code chunk.

Comment: The code below solves your problem. Use `Map(function, list1, list2, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are after something like this

```
Map(`*`, lst_A, lst_b[names(lst_A)])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, this is not working for me. I get the message "Error in rep(pars["r0"], nrow(data_in)) : invalid 'times' argument"

Comment: To be more specific, the problem is calling the bootstrap_CI function with the necessary terms inside Map(). Adapted from the code in the last chunk of the post, I have: 'test_cis <- Map(bootstrap_CI(data_in = lst_A, optim_pars = lst_b, n_iter = 10, times_matrix = times_matrix, intervals = c(14, 7, 3, 1), NLL_include = 5, cpp = TRUE), lst_A, lst_b[names(lst_A)]) ' and I get 'Error in rep(pars["r0"], nrow(data_in)) : invalid 'times' argument'